# How can I read csv data from a file and convert into json using CSV-connector in wso2 Integration studio?

Tags: json, csv, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-integration-studio

I am trying to read csv data from a file and convert it into json data by using the CSV-Connector in WSO2 Integration studio. The data is converted to json when I pass it as payload, but how do I do it when I want to read csv data from a file by using the Connector? What extra connectors or mediators might be required for the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to read the file using the [File Connector](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/connectors/file-connector/file-connector-overview/) or using the VFS transport. (Either use a [VFS Listener proxy](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.0.0/micro-integrator/use-cases/examples/file-processing/vfs-transport-examples/) or a [File Inbound Endpoint](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.0.0/micro-integrator/references/synapse-properties/inbound-endpoints/polling-inbound-endpoints/file-inbound-endpoint-properties/)). There is a File Inbound sample on the getting started page in the `Integration Studio`.

After reading the file youcan use the `CSV-Connector`, `Datamapper Mediator` or use the [Smooks Mediator](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.0.0/micro-integrator/references/mediators/smooks-Mediator/) to convert the CSV into a XML and then to a JSON.

Comment: I've tried using the read operation of FileConnector but I get the following error:
 [TestConnection]Failed to initiate file connector configuration. org.wso2.carbon.connector.exception.InvalidConfigurationException: Parameter 'fileLockScheme' contains empty value.

Comment: Did you enable `FileLock`? Try adding <fileLockScheme>Local</fileLockScheme> to your connector configurations.

Comment: Yea, after adding this it works. But the data comes out as Base64. I added the enrich mediator. How do I get the data as it is

Comment: Set the content type for the connector. `<contentType>text/csv</contentType>`

Answer (score 2):

You can use WSO2 File connector https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Working+with+the+File+Connector

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/File+Connector

or you can write new custom mediator https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Class+Mediator+ with your logic.

Comment: I did try reading the csv data using file connector, but it give me this error:
[TestConnection]Failed to initiate file connector configuration. org.wso2.carbon.connector.exception.InvalidConfigurationException: Parameter 'fileLockScheme' contains empty value.

Any idea why I'm getting this when trying to read?

Comment: can you add xml from your service?